# How to install MATLAB 2012b Mac OSX 10.9.2?

Tags: macos, matlab, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install MATLAB 2012b on my mac OSX 10.9.2 but when I run the installer I get the message:

> "You can’t open the application “InstallForMacOSX” because PowerPC
>   applications are no longer supported".

Is there anyway I could install the software?

Comment: R2012b is supported for Intel Macs and OS X 10.9. I use it myself. You seem to have obtained the wrong installer or are trying to use an installer from another PPC-based computer. You're not going to be able to run it on Mavericks [or any version of OS X 10.7+](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)). The only way to use this is on an old PPC machine or an Intel machine running OS X 10.6 or earlier. Or I suppose that you could try running it under virtualization software like VMware or VirtualPC.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/). Upgrading to Matlab R2014a will not do the trick, because you will have to go through the same process (however, Matlab 2013a does not need XQuartz installed strangely enough).